# Show both app icon and back arrow in ActionBar in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I am using `AppCompatV7` library in my project and I am wondering how to show both back arrow and app icon in my `ActionBar`. At the moment I am able to show only separate back arrow or app icon and have no idea how to show both of them (programmatically). Could you help me?

Comment: customise your actionBar and add custom layout for icon and text. backArrow will come by default at left.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about it, but at the moment trying to customize AB bar without custom layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

I tested and It works.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Actionbar Title");
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working! Sorry, can i ask one more related to the topic question? At the moment app icon is too big and has a lot of padding between back arrow. Can it be fixed via styles?

Comment: As I worked on Default Actionbar it doesn't allow you to resize the app icon on actionbar. and the left space is width of default back button, it means you can not apply these change on default Actionbar. But you can do this by Custom Actionbar. create your view and set it to actionbar custome view. Here is the example 
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: Thanks again, i'l ltry

Answer (score 0):

```
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    getSupportActionBar().setLogo("R.drawable.YourIcon");
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention - i need app title also to be present in ActionBar